# When element appears in the viewport run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a function so that when my `element` comes into view a function is attached to it.

I have a range of elements on my page, `element1`, `element2`, `element3` and I'd like to write a function that checks when either of these is in the viewport, rather than having a big if statement.

I have the following only this doesn't seem to work, and nothing happens?

```
var $findme = $('.section').each();

function Scrolled() {
    var findmeOffset = $findme.offset(),
        findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
        scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        visibleBottom = window.innerHeight;

    if (findmeTop < scrollTop + visibleBottom) {
        console.log('element is visible');
    }

}

function Setup() {
    var $top = $('#top'),
        $bottom = $('#bottom');

    $top.height(500);
    $bottom.height(500);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        Scrolled();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Setup();

});
```

---

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x3/

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: I've added a demo @PratikJoshi

Comment: now tell what output you want?

Comment: Check this fiddle I updated => http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x3/1/

Comment: When the element comes into view, i'd like it to alert the contents of the element

Comment: sorry, this fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x3/3/

Comment: Thanks @PratikJoshi, this doesnt alert the contents of the div though

Comment: ok i am doing coding.

Comment: Hello you use separate id for separate divs , How will u identify which is current div? Use id ,i am doing fiddle on ir

Answer (score 3):

Here is a woking solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x3/7/).

Your main problem is that you were using `$fimdme` in you `scroll` event handler, what caused that it only applied to the first element. Calling `.each()` to an element with no arguments has no effect at all.

Here's the new code. I modified it so, every time you scroll, the alert shows the text of a section if, and only if, it is visible now (in the viewport) and was not visible before, whether you scroll down or you scroll up.

```
var $findme = $('.section');

function Scrolled() {
    $findme.each(function() {
        var $section = $(this),
            findmeOffset = $section.offset(),
            findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
            findmeBottom = $section.height() + findmeTop,
            scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
            visibleBottom = window.innerHeight,
            prevVisible = $section.prop('_visible');

        if ((findmeTop > scrollTop + visibleBottom) ||
             findmeBottom < scrollTop) {
            visible = false;
        } else visible = true;

        if (!prevVisible && visible) {
            alert($section.text());
        }
        $section.prop('_visible', visible);
    });

}

function Setup() {
    var $top = $('#top'),
        $bottom = $('#bottom');

    $top.height(500);
    $bottom.height(500);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        Scrolled();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Setup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to your declaration of $findme. You're passing an array of HTML elements, but in Scrolled() you're looking for one specific top offset.

The demo you provided will work if you pass an id of one specific element rather than the class identifier of all elements.

Maybe you could update the code above to pass one identifier at a time to Scrolled(). I'm not sure how to accomplish this in the context of your application, sorry.